# How to place a number in the middle of string using python?

Tags: python

suppose a float number x=3.1234. I want to print this number in the middle of the string containing space in the left side and right side of x. string length will be variable. Precision of x will be variable. if string length=10 and precision=2 the output will be `"   3.14   "` Have any function in python that can return this?

Comment: should be closed

Comment: Whats string and whats exactly the requirement, please either post sample code or be more clear.

Comment: Do you really think explaining it in words is easier than showing an example which would've been much quicker and easier to come up with?

Comment: It will be displayed in fixed width with the set precision precision with centre alignment, and it is guaranteed that it will fit in the width. Given the number x, the width of the string and the precision with which the number should be displayed, return a string that should be shown.

Comment: what is "precision"? 3.1234 doesn't round to 3.14..

Comment: Take the [tour] and [ask]

Answer (score 1):

This is really nicely documented at https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

But since you clearly didn't have time to google for it:

```
>>> x = 3.1234
>>> length=10
>>> precision=2
>>> f"{x:^{length}.{precision}}"
'   3.1    '
```

I'm afraid your notion of *precision* doesn't agree with Python's in the default case. You can fix it by specifying `f`ixed point formatting instead of the default `g`eneral formatting:

```
>>> f"{x:^{length}.{precision}f}"
'   3.12   '
```

This notation is more perspicuous than calling the method `str.format()`. But in Python 3.5 and earlier you need to do this instead:

```
>>> "{x:^{length}.{precision}f}".format(x=x, length=length, precision=precision)
```

But no amount of fiddling with the format is going to make 3.1234 come out as 3.14. I suspect that that was an error in the question, but if you really meant it, then there is no alternative but adjust the value of `x` before formatting it. Here is one way to do that:

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> (Decimal(x) / Decimal ('0.02')).quantize(Decimal('1'), rounding=ROUND_UP) * Decimal('0.02')
Decimal('3.14')
```

This divides your number into a whole number of chunks of size 0.02, rounding up where necessary, then multiplies by 0.02 again to get the value you want.

Comment: f strings are only in python 3.6, might want to make this more general. It's also not nice to assume that OP knew the word 'format' is what they needed to google.